# Centos не понимает кириллические названия папок и файлов

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, локализация

Собственно проблема в названии вопроса.

Вот скриншот из cPanel:

[image]

При перекачке файлов из одного сервера на другой все кириллические файлы и папки отображаются как показано под цифрой 1.

После попытки переименовать папку из символов юникода в русский - отображаются знаки вопроса (на скрине по цифрой 2).

Рут доступ есть.

ОС CENTOS 6.5.

Вывод команды locale:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Подскажите куда копать, чтобы сервер нормально воспринимал кириллицу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Папки и файлы скорее всего созданы на винде или неверно установлена локаль.

Покажите мне вывод команды locale

p.s. Если файлы действительно с чужеродной системы, то сменить кодировку имен файлов можно с помощью утилиты convmv

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov, обновил вопрос. Насколько я понял, нужно чтобы вместо en_US стояло ru_RU ??

Comment: @mountpoint не обязательно. Главное что UTF-8. Файлы откуда взялись? На файловой системе (не в CPanel) видны также, или нормально?

Comment: файлы перекачаны с другого сервака, который тоже на Centos. сейчас посмотрю вывод команды locale на том сервере

Comment: В консоли файлы выглядят также? Перекачаны по FTP? с хоста на хост или через машину на windows?

Comment: @Anton Shevtsov, на первом серваке вывод locale точно такой же